# pxloader issues with loading image

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

**Hello everyone,**

I'm trying to implement the following pre-loader script [Pxloader](http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/#sample1) to load my image files. 
But I don't seem to understand as how to access the images once they have been loaded by the pxloader script.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do..

```
 ...
....
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/PxLoader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/PxLoaderImage.js"></script> 

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="768" height="780">
</canvas>   

<script type="text/javascript">

var loader = new PxLoader();

for(var i=0; i < 5; i++) { 
    var pxImage = new PxLoaderImage('images/alex'+i+'.jpg');
    pxImage.imageNumber = i + 1;
    loader.add(pxImage); 
}

loader.addProgressListener(function(e) { 
         document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML=" -> "+e.resource.imageNumber+" / "+ e.totalCount;
}); 


loader.addCompletionListener(function(e) { 
    var canvas = document.getElementById('sample1-canvas'), 
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'); 
        // THIS is where I want to draw one of the above pre-loaded images but I'm not sure how.. 
         ctx.drawImage( **image** , 0, 0);  
}); 

loader.start();

</script>
```

I would really appreciate if someone could give me some pointers as I'm unable to figure it out by my self :/ .. .

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store your new 5 new PxLoaderImage in an array or object.
Once loaded images are found in the .img property of the PxLoaderImage.

Comment: you're welcome ! maybe you could throw the authors of this lib a comment that one has to dig into the code to know how to finally use the loaded images.